# Getting angle between line and x-axis(horizontal top of screen)

Tags: javafx-8

I have created a basic program which draws shapes using graphics context.  A line object holds its own start and end points. I wish to use the first quadrant values that are standard when building in java.

I have tried to create `Point2D` objects which gave me incorrect values. Also I have tried *arctan2* and *arctan* which return the same value no matter which line I pass them. I cannot find my mistake whether it is my code or my math. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
double slope = (this.getEndY() - this.getyCoordinate()) / (this.getEndX() - this.getxCoordinate());
return MyLine.description + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(slope));

this is using the Point2D with three points:
        Point2D point = new Point2D(1, 0); // x- axis
        Point2D point1 = new Point2D(this.getxCoordinate(),this.getyCoordinate()); //p1(0,0)
        Point2D point2 = new Point2D(this.endX,this.getEndY());//p2(bottom right corner of window)
        double angle = point1.angle(point, point2);
        return MyLine.description + " " + angle;
```

The first attempt is the solution I found on the site already which returns `NaN`. 
The second is an attemp to us the Point2d API which returns 0.0. 
I am expecting it to read 45.0.

Comment: Figured out the problem I was using my rectangular screen dimensions so what I thought was 45 degrees was actually only 28 degrees from the top of my screen. This code does work.                                                                                    
                Point2D point = new Point2D(1, 0); // x- axis
  Point2D point2 = new Point2D(this.endX,this.endY);
  double angle = point.angle(point2);
  return MyLine.description + " " + angle;

Comment: If the values are finite, a result of `NaN` in the first calculation indicates that both dividend and divisor are zero. Please provide us with the input values for the numbers involved.

Comment: The input for point2 was (1880,1000) my screen size. I was expecting 45 degrees because this line divides a rectangle I drew on my screen in half but does not divide the screen itself in half. When I set point2 to (300,300) i receive the correct value of 45. I am now working to have this function work with lines that do not start at the origin.